# como obtener y modificar el texto de un <textarea> en typescript?

Tags: html5, typescript

Necesito obtener y modificar el texto de un

Tengo el siguente codigo:

```
const TextArea:HTMLElement = document.getElementById('textarea');
```

He intentado esto:

```
TextArea.value = 'new value';
```

Pero no funciona a diferencia de Javascript.
Tambien he intentado buscar un tipo HTML adecuado pero no encuentro la solucion.

Me podria decir como lo hago?

Answer (score 1):

El tipo (en *typescript*) de un `textarea` es el [`HTMLTextAreaElement`](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmltextareaelement.html).

Parece que tienen un mal maquetado en la página de la documentación... En cualquier caso, `HTMLTextAreaElement` tiene una propiedad `value`.

```
const area = document.getElementById(`textarea`) as HTMLTextAreaElement;
area.value = 'Some value';
```

De este modo obtendrías el elemento. Con sólo definir el tipo `HTMLTextAreaElement` a la variable no compilaría, ya que el método `getElementById` tiene un *return type* de `HTMLElement | null`. Por ello, hay que castearlo al tipo que querramos.

Espero que sirva.